# Nginx proxy_pass rewrite URL and Headers

Tags: nginx

I want request to

```
http://localhost/app/httpbin.org/anything?test=data@cookieValue
```

forwarded into

```
Get https://httpbin.org/anything?test=data
Cookie: myCookies=cookieValue
```

I tried below but it return 404

```
location ~* ^/app/(.*?)@(.*){
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header  Cookie myCookies=$2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem is nginx regex only match `path` or

```
/httpbin.org/anything
```

not parameter or query string

```
?test=data@cookieValue
```

to solve the problem I change the URL to

```
http://localhost/app/cookieValue/httpbin.org/anything?test=data
```

and here the config

```
location ~ ^/app/([^\/]+)/(.*){
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://$2$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header  Cookie myCookie=$1;
}
```